# How can I display the date on actual photos taken with iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, software-recommendation, photos

I need some photos that I have taken to be dated. The date must be displayed on the actual photo (in a similar fashion to how one would think of film photos), but I have no idea how to do this? My understanding is there is an app that does this, but I haven't been able to find it.

Is there an app, or any other way, that would facilitate this?

Comment: Do you desire to have this done with the push of a button, or would you not mind manually typing the date?

Comment: I wouldnt mind manually typing the date I just need it to appear on the photo so I can send this on/print it

Answer (score 2):

[DateCam S](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/datecam-s-put-date-on-your/id325080036?mt=8) is a free app that will add the date to photos that you take automatically.

> This app simply adds date on your photos.
>
> So now, you can see when the photos were taken!

There are also apps that let you manually add any text (e.g. a date) to your photos. I have used and recommend [Camera+](http://campl.us) due to its stylistic formatting of the text.

Answer (score 2):

[Jambula](http://jambula.sourceforge.net/) is a free and open source product that can batch insert shooting date/time/comment on a jpeg image in different formats and languages. A special feature is that the date stamp is lossless.

> JAMBULA is a specialized software to solve a common need when taking digital pictures: to imprint the date/time and also comments on the picture.
>
> [image]

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of apps that will do this, such as [Timestamp It](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/timestamp-it-make-your-photos/id327756085?mt=8), [TimeStamp Photo](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/timestamp-photo-gps-address/id582538300?mt=8) and [Moment Diary](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/moment-diary/id352263913?mt=8), the latter of which is free.

The included Camera app does not have this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Photo Timestamps is a third party app that provides this information. It's not free, but it's also not $4.99. It's got a really clean, minimal interface (obligatory disclosure: I made it).

Answer (score -1):

I had this same annoyance - trying to sort thousands of unorganized photos, quickly, by date. The best solution so far:
1) Right click on the photo,
2) Click Get Info,
3) Leave the Get Info window up while organizing.
This process allows me to click on any image and the Get Into window updates the info instantly.[image]